# Error adding module: Several files providing this module

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to install the [react-native-navigation-drawer](https://github.com/ilansas/react-native-navigation-drawer) on my project with the command `yarn add react-native-navigation-drawer`.

After executing the command I get an error when I run the app.

```
/Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native/package.json
2017-10-16 15:10:43.664017+0200 mobilizeit[23431:100610] Ambiguous resolution: module '/Users/reactProject/index.ios.js' tries to require 'react-native', but there are several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them: 

/Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill/node_modules/react-native/package.json

/Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native-navigation-drawer/node_modules/react-native/package.json

/Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native-tab-view/node_modules/react-native/package.json

/Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native/package.json
```

I am very new with react-native. Can you help me solve the issue?
**EDIT:**

with the command `yarn start --reset-cache` I get a lot of warnings that look like:

```
This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: Sample
  Paths: /Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native-navigation-drawer/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Sample/Sample.ios.js collides with /Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Sample/Sample.ios.js

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: Settings
  Paths: /Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native-navigation-drawer/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/Settings.ios.js collides with /Users/reactProject/node_modules/react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings/Settings.ios.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
 yarn start --reset-cache
```